# How to check if datetime object in CPP is null or not

Tags: c++, datetime, c++17

I am using `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point;` this in my abstract class (header file) .

my code is as below

```
using datetime = std::chrono::system_clock::time_point;

class 

datetime _endDate;
```

Now in my cpp file, I want to check if it has a value different than epoch .How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not null"? It's not a pointer, it cannot be null. Are you trying to check if it has a value different than epoch?

Comment: I want to check whether value assigned to my endDate or not?

Comment: yes exactly, different than epoch

Comment: @ElvinJafarov: Why would it be "different than epoch"? What else would a default constructor do?

Comment: @ElvinJafarov You can't check whether a value has been assigned to a variable or not. I suspect that you're making invalid assumptions based on other languages you've encountered.

Comment: I am  trying to check if it has a value different than epoch @molbdnilo

Comment: `_endDate.time_since_epoch() != 0` or `_endDate != datetime{}`. First would be more readable to me. Although, I'd try to avoid situation where you can have invalid timepoint like that and use `std::optional<datetime>` or exceptions wherever an invalid `datetime` may be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did as it said in comment secion.

I used `_endDate != datetime{}`